# Google finance request to get volume data

Tags: google-finance, google-finance-api

http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ%3aGOOG
This returns realtime last price with no delay (like 15 min in yahoo). Is it possible to get current volume of the day from the google finance?

Comment: 5 years later and no answer or discussion... wondering if I found the black hole of stackoverflow?

FWIW: I'm using googlefinance.client  
https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance.client/  

it doesn't appear to be returning volume data. found this thread while looking for a solution.

So I'm in the dark also. :)